# VBA recording column names past column Z

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that has been working fine for ages trouble is now my data has gone past column z and the code no longer works, once it gets past column z the rangestring value is[29 rather than AA29 ,AB29 etc. can anyone give me guidance on how I can make this work it needs to go to at least column AW. other people have told me I have made a fundamental error because I should have used column numbers and not names. I am no expert and have managed to get this working by cannibalising code I have found on here and other places. My code is below hopefully it is understandable.

```
Sub Copy_picked_X1s_to_final_56()
    Dim SelectedName() As String              'this array holds the "SelectedName" for a specific date
    Dim AllNames() As Variant                  'this array holds all the names in the "Final Assignments"
    Dim NameCount1 As Long, NameCount2 As Long 'namecount 1 holds a count of the "SelectedName", namecount 2 holds a count of "AllNames" in the "Final Assignments"
    Dim Services() As Variant                  'this array holds a list of all the "Services"
    Dim Columncounter As Long                  'this array holds a count of all the columns that have "Services"
    Dim NameCell As String                     'this string holds the location of the cell in "Final Assignments" where the "SelectedName" appears
    Dim location As String
    Dim Name1 As String
    Dim Name2 As String
    Dim NameFound As Long
    Dim FillArray As Long                      'used to loop through the various arrays
    Dim RangeString As String
    Dim ServiceCount As Long

    '***********************************************************************************************'
    ' Fill the services array with the full list of services and loop through the services
    '***********************************************************************************************'

    Sheets("Final Assignments").Select 'select "Final Assignments" worksheet
    ServiceCount = Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count - 1 'set range of "Services" to count

    ReDim Services(0 To ServiceCount) 'Redimension the "Services" array

    For Columncounter = 0 To ServiceCount
        'Services(Columncounter) = Range("B3").Offset(0, Columncounter).Value 'collect the values
    Next Columncounter

    '***********************************************************************************************'
    ' Loop through all the services
    '***********************************************************************************************'

    For Columncounter = 0 To ServiceCount

        Sheets("Sorted X1").Select 'select "Sorted X1" worksheet
        RangeString = Chr(65 + Columncounter) & "29" 'set the range based on the columncounter

        NameCount1 = Range(RangeString, Range(RangeString).End(xlDown)).Cells.Count - 1 'count the number of names for the first date

        ReDim SelectedName(0 To NameCount1) 'Redimension the "SelectedName" array
        If SelectedName(0) = "" And SelectedName(1) = "" And NameCount1 = 1 Then
            For FillArray = 0 To NameCount1 'gather the names

                SelectedName(FillArray) = Range(RangeString).Offset(FillArray).Value
            Next FillArray
        End If

        '***********************************************************************************************'
        'Now select the first name in the final assignments list
        '***********************************************************************************************'

        Sheets("Final Assignments").Select 'select "Final Assignments" worksheet
        NameCount2 = Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Count - 1 'count the number of "AllNames" in the "Final Assignments"
        Range("A3").Select
        If NameCount1 < 4 Then
            For NameFound = 0 To NameCount2
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

                For FillArray = 0 To NameCount1

                    If SelectedName(FillArray) = ActiveCell.Value Then
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, Columncounter + 1).Value = "X1"   'Services(Columncounter)
                    End If

                Next FillArray

            Next NameFound
        End If
    Next Columncounter 'increment along the row

End Sub
```

Comment: this looks a mess I doubt if anyone can make head or tail of this, I think I may have to redo it..........sigh

Comment: Indent your code with 4 spaces or place ALL code between the ` tags.. this is a mess

Comment: @Graham Can you review quickly but think it's sorted

Comment: yes that looks right now thank you Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty fix would be to replace this line

```
RangeString = Chr(65 + Columncounter) & "29"
```

with something like

```
RangeString = Cells(29, ColumnCounter+1).address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

This should generate the `RangeString` variable without being dependent on `Chr(`. In this I've added one to your `ColumnCounter` as the loop starts at 0 which is less than the minimum of 1 for a Column.

Comment: Tom thank you so much that works a treat, I am happy to take a quick and dirty fix as this line of code is in several other modules, and it would be a lot of work to rewrite all the modules to make the code more "elegant".

Comment: np - Often a quick and dirty fix is the most logical way to go. But in future consider writing your new code so that you don't fall into these traps again :). If this has solved your answer don't forget to click on the tick to the left of the answer/click on the upvote

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in:

`RangeString = Chr(65 + Columncounter) & "29" 'set the range based on the columncounter`

This part of the code would work indeed up to `Z`. Which is not a good option. Use the `Offset` property, to get the correct address. E.g., the code below gives the address of the 5000th column of the first row:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim addCols As Long: addCols = 5000

    Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    Debug.Print myRange.Offset(0, addCols).Address

End Sub
```

Or even get the new range as a range, without assigning its address to a variable:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range, newRange as Range
    Dim addCols As Long: addCols = 5000

    Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    Set newRange = myRange.Offset(0, addCols)
    Debug.Print newRange.Address

End Sub
```